# No figures or tables on this page

Tags: floats

Occasionally there are "special pages" on which I do not want to have any figures or tables (e.g., cover pages).

Usually I solve this by simply putting all floats sufficiently late in the source code so that they never appear on the special page.

Is there any cleaner solution? Can I easily implement a `\nofloatsonthispage` macro?

Comment: I normally used the `placeins` package and `\FloatBarrier`. [Related/duplicate question?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @MikeRenfro: How can you achieve "no floats on this page" with placeins & \FloatBarrier? To me it seems that placeins only helps to make sure that floats are placed **near** the point in which they appear in the source code, while I would like to do the opposite (do *not* put floats on this page even if it is possible)?

Comment: Neither of these options is an exact solution: first, once you know the first page of text, and assuming the floats are relatively large, you can place a `\FloatBarrier` between two paragraphs near the end of the first page. Second, using the `[section]` option to the `placeins` package will force floats defined in a particular section to be placed in that section. If the first section of a chapter has no floats, and takes up around one page, you'll get no floats there.

Comment: Did you consider omitting the `figure` or `table` environment around a specific graph or `tabular` environment. You could place them basically everywhere and do not bother with floats in this case

Answer (score 2):

Here is some "bold" code disabling and enabling float placement:

`\DeferAllFloats` stops float placement from that point onwards for all floats that are not yet placed (i.e., already deferred or encountered later).

`\AllowFloats` reallows float placement.

In a two-column document those commands act on the column level, e.g., if `\AllowFloats` is placed somewhere in the first column of the page the second column may receive floats again. Similar to ensure that the next page is not getting any floats one may has to place `\DeferAllFloats` somewhere near the end of the previous page (to prevent any floats already waiting to be set from being placed).

So perhaps not perfect, but ... (I probably could have gotten away with less settings but that would have required a bit more thinking on dependencies).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@nofloats
\def\AllowFloats{\global\let\if@nofloats\iffalse}
\def\DeferAllFloats{\global\let\if@nofloats\iftrue\@floatplacement}
\AllowFloats
\AtEndDocument\AllowFloats

\def\@floatplacement{%
 \if@nofloats
   \global\@topnum\z@
    % Textpage bit, global:
   \global\@toproom \z@
   \global\@botnum  \z@
   \global\@botroom \z@
   \global\@colnum  \z@
    % Floatpage bit, local:
   \@fpmin   1.1\@colht
 \else
   \global\@topnum\c@topnumber
    % Textpage bit, global:
   \global\@toproom \topfraction\@colht
   \global\@botnum  \c@bottomnumber
   \global\@botroom \bottomfraction\@colht
   \global\@colnum  \c@totalnumber
    % Floatpage bit, local:
   \@fpmin   \floatpagefraction\@colht
 \fi
}

\def \@dblfloatplacement {%
 \if@nofloats
  \global \@dbltopnum \z@
  \global \@dbltoproom \z@
  \@textmin \@colht
  \@fpmin 1.1\textheight
 \else
  \global \@dbltopnum \c@dbltopnumber
  \global \@dbltoproom \dbltopfraction\@colht
  \@textmin \@colht
  \advance \@textmin -\@dbltoproom
  \@fpmin \dblfloatpagefraction\textheight
  \@fptop \@dblfptop
  \@fpsep \@dblfpsep
  \@fpbot \@dblfpbot
 \fi
}
\makeatother

%%% remainder is for testing

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\Afloat[1]{\begin{figure}A float\hrulefill\caption{#1}\end{figure}}
\newcommand\Wfloat[1]{\begin{figure*}A wide float\hrulefill\caption{#1}\end{figure*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\Afloat{A}
\Wfloat{B}

\DeferAllFloats
\Afloat{C}

\lipsum[2-21]


XXXX --- here we allow floats again ---

\AllowFloats

\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```